# E/Volley: [6681] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL null

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with java volley when ever I sent a request to download it gives an error Bad URL null which I'm not understanding why its doing this.
I am using open weather map for the json to download.
the code sets the url in the on click method then calls the JSON downloader code below.

```
public String Weather = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + LocationID + "&APPID=99b1346cd10b7389a4592e7f3123a412&units=imperial";
```

an example of the above LocationID would be 2657832 making the url:
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=2657832&APPID=99b1346cd10b7389a4592e7f3123a412&units=imperial
which works if you enter it in a web brouser

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, webAdress,
        null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        String RESP = response.toString();
        TEXT.setText("Response: " + RESP);
        Log.d("TAG", "onResponse: " + webAdress);
        Log.d("RESP", "onResponse: " + RESP);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        TEXT.setText("That didn't work!");
        Log.d("TAG", "onErrorResponse: " + webAdress);
    }
});
```

The on click method that sets the URL

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){

     switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.BTN_fav1:
            LocationID = fave1S;
            Weather = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + LocationID + "&APPID=99b1346cd10b7389a4592e7f3123a412";
            webAdress = Weather;

            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            Log.d("TAG", "onClick: " + LocationID + "  " + webAdress);

        break;
```

but here's the kicker if I set the URL in the json request as JOSN_WEB instead of webAdress, a url we got from a course work it works

```
public String JSON_WEB = "http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/sitelist?key=0732c29d-95d4-41e3-9903-5a9244b3cd5b";
```

The complete code:

```
package com.example.ewan.coursework;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

enter code herepublic class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "SHARED_PREFS";

public static final String fave1 = "Fave1";
public static final String fave2 = "Fave2";
public static final String fave3 = "Fave3";
public static final String fave4 = "Fave4";
public static final String fave5 = "Fave5";

private String fave1S;
private String fave2S;
private String fave3S;
private String fave4S;
private String fave5S;

Button BTN_fav1;
Button BTN_fav2;
Button BTN_fav3;
Button BTN_fav4;
Button BTN_fav5;

public String LocationName;
public String LocationID;
public String JSON_WEB = "http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/sitelist?key=0732c29d-95d4-41e3-9903-5a9244b3cd5b";
public String Weather = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + LocationID + "&APPID=99b1346cd10b7389a4592e7f3123a412&units=imperial";
public String webAdress;
public String[] location;
public String[] favourites;
public Spinner SP_location;
RequestQueue queue;
TextView TEXT;
AutoCompleteTextView ACTV;
Button BTN_search;
Button BTN_settings;

private static final String Key_Value = "value";


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(Key_Value,String.valueOf(TEXT.getText()));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BTN_fav1 = findViewById(R.id.BTN_fav1);
    BTN_fav2 = findViewById(R.id.BTN_fav2);
    BTN_fav3 = findViewById(R.id.BTN_fav3);
    BTN_fav4 = findViewById(R.id.BTN_fav4);
    BTN_fav5 = findViewById(R.id.BTN_fav5);

    BTN_fav1.setOnClickListener(this);
    BTN_fav2.setOnClickListener(this);
    BTN_fav3.setOnClickListener(this);
    BTN_fav4.setOnClickListener(this);
    BTN_fav5.setOnClickListener(this);

    BTN_search = findViewById(R.id.BTN_search);
    BTN_search.setOnClickListener(this);

    BTN_settings = findViewById(R.id.BTN_settings);
    BTN_settings.setOnClickListener(this);

    TEXT = findViewById(R.id.TV_result_test);

    Resources res = getResources();
    location = res.getStringArray(R.array.locations);

    ACTV = findViewById(R.id.ACTV_search);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,location);
    ACTV.setAdapter(adapter);

    queue  = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        TEXT.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(Key_Value));
    }

    loadData();
    updateViews();

    try{URL url = new URL(webAdress);} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v){

     switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.BTN_fav1:
            LocationID = fave1S;
            Weather = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + LocationID + "&APPID=99b1346cd10b7389a4592e7f3123a412";
            webAdress = Weather;

            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            Log.d("TAG", "onClick: " + LocationID + "  " + webAdress);

        break;

        case R.id.BTN_fav2:
            LocationID = fave2S;
            Weather = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=\" + LocationID + \"&APPID=99b1346cd10b7389a4592e7f3123a412&units=imperial";
            webAdress = Weather;

            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            Log.d("TAG", "onClick: " + webAdress);
            break;

        case R.id.BTN_fav3:
            LocationID = fave3S;
            Weather = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + LocationID + "&APPID=99b1346cd10b7389a4592e7f3123a412&units=imperial";
            webAdress = Weather;

            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            Log.d("TAG", "onClick: " + webAdress);
            break;

        case R.id.BTN_fav4:
            LocationID = fave4S;
            Weather = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + LocationID + "&APPID=99b1346cd10b7389a4592e7f3123a412&units=imperial";
            webAdress = Weather;

            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            Log.d("TAG", "onClick: " + webAdress);
            break;

        case R.id.BTN_fav5:
            LocationID = fave5S;
            Weather = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + LocationID + "&APPID=99b1346cd10b7389a4592e7f3123a412&units=imperial";
            webAdress = Weather;

            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            Log.d("TAG", "onClick: " + webAdress);
            break;

        case R.id.BTN_search:
            LocationID = ACTV.getText().toString();
            Weather = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=" + LocationID + "&APPID=99b1346cd10b7389a4592e7f3123a412&units=imperial";
            webAdress = Weather;

            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            Log.d("TAG", "onClick: " + webAdress);
            break;

        case R.id.BTN_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,settings.class));
            break;
    }
}

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_WEB,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                TEXT.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        TEXT.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});


JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, webAdress,
        null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        String RESP = response.toString();
        TEXT.setText("Response: " + RESP);
        Log.d("TAG", "onResponse: " + webAdress);
        Log.d("RESP", "onResponse: " + RESP);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        TEXT.setText("That didn't work!");
        Log.d("TAG", "onErrorResponse: " + webAdress);
    }
});


public void loadData()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    fave1S = sharedPreferences.getString(fave1, "Favorite not set");
    fave2S = sharedPreferences.getString(fave2, "Favorite not set");
    fave3S = sharedPreferences.getString(fave3, "Favorite not set");
    fave4S = sharedPreferences.getString(fave4, "Favorite not set");
    fave5S = sharedPreferences.getString(fave5, "Favorite not set");
    Log.d("tag", "loadData: " + fave1 + " saved as " + fave1S);
}
public void updateViews()
{
    BTN_fav1.setText(fave1S);
    BTN_fav2.setText(fave2S);
    BTN_fav3.setText(fave3S);
    BTN_fav4.setText(fave4S);
    BTN_fav5.setText(fave5S);
}
}
```

Thanks for any advice. Ewan

Comment: I tried changing to the MET office weather service to no joy.
I've found that the code seems to work if I set the URL as a whole in the declarations at the top but not when I try pass the Location ID from the on click, is it to do with the JSON request taking the URL when its created rather than when it's called? if so how would I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 final ThreadLocal<JsonObjectRequest> jsonObjectRequest = new ThreadLocal<JsonObjectRequest>() {
    @Override
    protected JsonObjectRequest initialValue() {
        return new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, webAdress,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                RESP = response.toString();
                TEXT.setText("Response: " + RESP);
                Log.d("TAG", "onResponse: " + webAdress);
                Log.d("RESP", "onResponse: " + RESP);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                TEXT.setText("That didn't work!");
                Log.d("TAG", "onErrorResponse: " + webAdress);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

fixed the problem  now downloads the data from met office fine.